# How to change the day and month language?

Tags: 7, datetime

Working on multilingual site, I want to change the language of the month in dutch language. For that I have created a module.

```
<?php
function mymodule_format_date($timestamp, $type = 'custom', $format = 'd M', $timezone = NULL) {
  return format_date($timestamp, $type, $format, $timezone, 'nl');
}
```

and on the node file put the date format in t() function

```
<?php print t(format_date($created, 'custom', 'd M')); ?>
```

but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For multilingual you need to import .po file in your setup. Download .po file from this link just add language prefix at here **language_prefix (/en, /hi, /de etc..)**.

https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/language_prefix

Now, add `<?php print date('j F Y', $created) ?>` simple php data function and add your data formate here.

After you will able to see day and month in your language.

If you wish to make a different format for both language just add this.

`<?php if($language->language == "language_prefix") {
  print date('j F Y', $created); 
} 
else {
  print date('F j Y', $created);
}`

Thank you.